# Adding two newsletter form in homepage - magento

Tags: magento

i am using two newsletter form like the below link

http://www.astleyclarke.com/uk/jewellery-care

One is using mouse over function the email subscriber is popping up 
and second 1 at the bottom. If I comment on any one  of the forms then the other 1 is working fine. 
Could any 1 help me solve this, or may have done with this.

below is the code for header.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.login-window').click(function() {

        // Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        jQuery(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        jQuery(loginBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        jQuery('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        jQuery('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    jQuery('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      jQuery('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        jQuery('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
});
</script>

 <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>

      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

</div>
```

for footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: can you provide the code

Comment: yes bro edited pls find the code above